# List Item property 'Content Type' not updating - SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, content-type

I have added a content type (& its columns) using powershell to Content Type Hub.
I want to change the content types of all items in a document library in a site collection to the new one. I first added the new CT to the document library and then manually tried changing the content type of an item. I dont get any error but the property does not change for some files for eg., a .docx or .xlsx , but updates for a .txt file.
Any idea about this behaviour?
How can i solve it?

Comment: can you, please, explain what ` I dont get any error but the property does not change for some files` means? I'm not sure I understand it. You are saying that you changed content type from `Document` to `CustomContentType`, but you can't see columns associated with `CustomContentType` when opening the Edit/Display form of the document?

Comment: I am able to see the customContentTypes and its columns on the edit properties form, but when i save it, the content type field does not show any changes, but the columns associated to my custom content type gets updated accordingly.